# QML runtime error with singleton object: instantiated recursively?

Tags: singleton, qml, qtquick2

I'm getting a runtime error for a new QML singleton type I just created:

```
qrc:///Components/RunStatus.qml:-1 RunStatus is instantiated recursively
```

I have another QML singleton object that works just fine and I compared the two and there are no obvious differences.

Here's the source for RunStatus.qml:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.6
import Components 1.0

Item {
    property bool isRunning: false
    property bool isStopped: !isRunning
}
```

There's the source for my qmldir file:

```
#  singleton QML files
singleton RunStatus  1.0  RunStatus.qml
```

I eliminated all references to the object, `RunStatus` and I still get the error. However, when I remove the `singleton` keyword from the qmldir file the runtime error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following `import` statement from RunStatus.qml:

```
import Components 1.0
```

Importing the folder with the qmldir that declares the singleton qml object causes the recursive instantiation.

Comment: What if your singleton requires elements defined in Components?

Comment: If the singleton requires elements defined in Components, the qmldir that declares the singleton should be imported from a folder other than the Components folder.

Comment: the better way is to add the stuff that need the import into a separate qml file, and use that one (without the import) in the singleton.
That way everything works